# LLDB Error: Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations

Tags: macos, breakpoints, lldb, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to use LLDB (because I apparently can't use gdb anymore) to debug som of my code and each time I try to...

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -f file.c -l 65
```

I get...

```
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending)
WARNING: Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

I've tried different things like assigning the breakpoint to a function and such but I always get the same error. When running there's no break. Please help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### lldb: resolving breakpoints to locations

If your `out` file doesn't have debugging symbols enabled for `Code Generation Options` then breakpoints likely can't be resolved to locations within your `.c` source file.

When you create your `out` file enable debug information:

```
$ clang -g -O0 file.c -o file
$ lldb file
(lldb) target create "file"
Current executable set to 'file' (x86_64).
(lldb) b file.c:13
Breakpoint 1: where = file`main + 29 at file.c:13, address = 0x0000000100000f4d
```

Using the `-g` option adds the necessary debug information to your file for `lldb`. It should now resolve when you `breakpoint set -f file.c -l n` (which can be abbreviated as `b file.c:n`).

> `-g`  Generate debug information.  Note that Clang debug information
> works best at `-O0`.

### [**Code Generation Options**](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#code-generation-options)

```
-O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, -Ofast, -Os, -Oz, -Og, -O, -O4
```

**Specify which optimization level to use:**

> -O0 Means “no optimization”: this level compiles the fastest and generates the most debuggable code.
>
> -O1 Somewhere between -O0 and -O2.
>
> -O2 Moderate level of optimization which enables most optimizations.
>
> -O3 Like -O2, except that it enables optimizations that take longer to perform or that may generate larger code (in an attempt to make the
> program run faster).
>
> -Ofast Enables all the optimizations from -O3 along with other aggressive optimizations that may violate strict compliance with
> language standards.
>
> -Os Like -O2 with extra optimizations to reduce code size.
>
> -Oz Like -Os (and thus -O2), but reduces code size further.
>
> -Og Like -O1. In future versions, this option might disable different optimizations in order to improve debuggability.
>
> -O Equivalent to -O1.
>
> -O4 and higher currently equivalent to -O3

Comment: what does the -O0 option do?

Comment: Also, if this still doesn't work, try setting a breakpoint on a function name instead of a file. lldb behavior here seems inconsistent, as I'm able to set breakpoint like `b file:lineno` on some programs, but not others.

Comment: The -O0 solved my problem. -O1 was still optimizing out locals and the ability to set many break points.

Comment: Adding many years later that I also had this problem, but I was using -Og, which I assumed would work but didn't. Switching to -O0 fixed the issue. I know very little about the difference, others could perhaps elucidate. Using Apple flavor of clang/lldb.

Comment: @laxcat, Check edit - hopefully that helps.